# Difficulty with SendAsync HttpPost with header and body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Having difficulty getting a `200` response back from SendAsync for an HttpPost. This is for a multi-phase authentication using a basic authentication token to get a bearer token which is then used to get an accessKeyId and accessKeySecret which is then used to get a usable accessToken.

This is the format that is expected (provided by the vendor). I believe the code I have written handles the Header data correctly, but I am not sure about the body. When testing with Restlet or Postman the body must be entered exactly as shown. I think when the quoted tag and value are placed in C# the quotes are being lost in translation; see code below this section.

*************************From the Vendor*****************************
With a bearer token an access key can now be created using endpoint
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/x-keys`
a.POST Request:
    i. Header:
            1. Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9….
            2. Content-Type: application/json
    ii.  Body:
            1.  {
            2.  "userId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            3.  "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            4.  }

```
>String newBearerToken = "bearer " + bearerToken;

>var cl = new HttpClient();
>cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
>cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", newBearerToken);

>var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
>nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("\"" + "userId" + "\"", "\"" +   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\""));
>nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("\"" + "tenantId" + "\"", "\"" + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\""));

>var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/-keys") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };
>var result = await cl.SendAsync(req);
```

I expect a response body with new access tokens and an HttpResponse of 200 but this is what is returned:

> "result {StatusCode: 302, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Content-Security-Policy:
>   default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
>   connect-src...."

Comment: A `302` response is a redirdct. Did you get a `Location` header?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication header should be the following...

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", newBearerToken);
```

not "Authorization" if you're using bearer tokens

Your current implementation is doing the following

Authorization: **Authorization bearer** eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9

Remove the bearer from the token too

```
String newBearerToken = bearerToken;
```